# Does every Blizzard add-on require one game account?

Tags: battle.net, starcraft-2

Here is what I want to know:

Once Starcraft 2: Heart of the Swarm (HotS) is released I want to have 2 copies of the game, so I have a main account and another one for goofing around. I do own one account of Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty (WoL).

Can I buy two copies of HotS and register them on my WoL account without buying the base game again or do I need two WoL licenses one for each HotS?

This is important because if the latter is the case, I would just create a new Blizzard account for the second HotS game, otherwise I would save the money for a second WoL.

This question is directed to all Blizzard games, but specifically on the not yet released Starcraft 2: Heart of the Swarm.

Edit: Just to clarify my question:

I want to get 2 accounts for HotS. I have the following setup:

Battle.Net Account (john.doe@example.com):

- Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty (1)

Do I need to get:

Battle.Net Account (john.doe@example.com):

- Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty (1)
- Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty (2)
- Starcraft 2: Heart of the Swarm (1)
- Starcraft 2: Heart of the Swarm (2)

Which I could also layout like this:

Battle.Net Account (john.doe@example.com):

- Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty (1)
- Starcraft 2: Heart of the Swarm (1)

Battle.Net Account (john@example.com):

- Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty (2)
- Starcraft 2: Heart of the Swarm (2)

Or would the following suffice:

Battle.Net Account (john.doe@example.com):

- Starcraft 2: Wings of Liberty (1)
- Starcraft 2: Heart of the Swarm (1)
- Starcraft 2: Heart of the Swarm (2)

I do know that I need to meet the prerequisites for every Addon.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question properly, in order to have two Heart of the Swarm licenses you need two Wings of Liberty licenses.

Since Heart of the Swarm is not a stand alone expansion, you need to have all the prerequisite games in order to play it (each copy).

You can see for example, on this Cataclysm box art for World of Warcraft, that it requires "Wrath of the Lich King to play". Wotlk says it requires TBC, and TBC requires the base game. It is expansions all the way down. This trend stands true for all Blizzard games to date, as they don't release stand alone expansions.

[image]

Comment: Yeah I know that. But do I have to fulfill the prerequisites multiple times (getting multiple WoL) on one account in order to get multiple HotS?

Comment: Yes, that is in the answer.